# Is there any existing server side session handling framework/library to use with httpcomponents core?

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

I am using httpcomponents to build a simple http server. As far as I understand, there is no built-in implementation of http session handling. Has anyone already done it? is there any framework to build session handling? any simple httpcomponents based server you may suggest?

thanks a lot in advance,
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

For political reasons server side aspects of the project were always deemphasized. There is no built-in HTTP session handling in core and I am not aware of any 3rd party implementation.